# Modifying Results Table to use AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP website that allows users to search a library catalog and then select/add books to a shopping cart. This all works well but we would like to implement AJAX into the search results table so that instead of clicking a link which runs another php script to add the selected record to their cart, it does this inline within the same page. This will remove the search results page refreshing when they "select" a record and it pops back to the top of the page (annoying if you were at the bottom of the page).

I've found a similar example of implementing AJAX with a  link - this is my first time with AJAX - but I'm stuck as nothing happens when the user clicks the link.

Here's my script:

```
function selectRecord() {
   // Allocate an XMLHttpRequest object
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
      // IE6, IE5
      var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   // Set up the readyState change event handler
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ((this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200)) {
         document.getElementById("selectRecord").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
   }
   // Open an asynchronous POST connection and send request
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "selectRecord.php", true);
   return false;  // Do not follow hyperlink
}
```

and here's the table cell with the link:

```
<td class="hidden-narrow" id="selectRecord">
                <?php
                if (in_array($bookID, $_SESSION['selectedBooks'])) {
                    echo "Selected";
                } else {
                echo '<a href="select" onclick="return selectRecord()" class="center">Select</a>';
                }
                ?>
                </td>
```

In case it's not clear the result I'm after is a link ("Select") in the table cell - when the user clicks this link it then performs the selectRecord.php script which will echo "Selected" or an error message if there was an error. At present nothing happens when the user clicks the Select link.

I also need to work out how to pass the $bookID PHP variable to the AJAX script so the selectRecord.php knows which Book ID to add to the cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a parameter to your selectRecord() call like this:

```
echo '<a href="select" onclick="return selectRecord('.$bookID.')" class="center">Select</a>';
```

Then your selectRecord function should look like this:

```
function selectRecord(id) {
   // Allocate an XMLHttpRequest object
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
      // IE6, IE5
      var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   // Set up the readyState change event handler
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ((this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200)) {
         document.getElementById("selectRecord").innerHTML="Selected";
      }
   }
   // Open an asynchronous POST connection and send request
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "selectRecord.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send("id="+id);
   return false;  // Do not follow hyperlink
}
```

This works well as long there is only one element in your document with id selectRecord. You can always modify the id of any link by simply adding the BookId number as a postfix.
Please note your code wasn't working because it was missing the .open call on the xmlHttpRequest object which actually perform the request.

Comment: That works well - I did have to add one extra line in the script to work with my server: xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");